# How to normalize big numbers into customized ranges?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do we normalize a big range of values like 0 to 46000 into a customized range of 0.7842 to 1?

I wonder if that is possible.

Thank you!

Comment: This was taught in elementary school or early middle school to most people.  Just make a line passing through the points $(0,0.7842)$ and $(46000,1)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz ...unless you're in the United States, then it's likely you learned this in high school.